# Fill data between timepoints under set criteria

Tags: r, time, timestamp, missing-data

I have a dataset of remote sensing data that has false negative time gaps I want to fill. I only want to fill the gaps, however, if the individual is the same, at the same location. I also don't want to fill gaps longer than 20 seconds.

e.g. this data

```
DateTime                 Individual   Location
"2019-07-25 07:10:21"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:22"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:24"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:29"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:50"    A            B1
```

will become this:

```
DateTime                 Individual   Location
"2019-07-25 07:10:21"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:22"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:23"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:24"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:25"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:26"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:27"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:28"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:29"    A            B1
"2019-07-25 07:10:50"    A            B1
```

In principle it's very similar to this question in python: [Fill timestamp gaps in large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487007/fill-timestamp-gaps-in-large-dataset) , except I also want to copy all other associated columns (individual, location and a couple of other potential bits).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't offer a complete solution, but you could have a look at the fill_gaps methode from the tsibble package (method for filling implicitly missing values) and the group_by  + fill methods from tidyverse.